# $x$ and $f(x)$ are linear dependent then $f(x) = kx$.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $U$ be an infinite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $f: U \to U$ is a linear map. Suppose for every $x_0 \in U$, $x_0$ and $f(x_0)$ are linear dependent.

Prove that there exists an $k \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = kx,\forall x \in U$.

I know that the problem is not correct in finite dimensional vector space, but I don't have good idea about solving it.

I also want some good problem book about linear operators in infinite dimensional vector space.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Let $0\ne x \in U$. As $x$ and $f(x)$ are linearly dependent, there is a unique $\lambda(x) \in \mathbb R$ such that
$$ f(x) = \lambda(x)x.$$
If $x,y \in U$ are linearly independent, by
$$ \lambda(x+y)(x+y) = f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y) = \lambda(x)x + \lambda(y)y $$
we have
$$ \lambda(x) = \lambda(x+y) = \lambda(y) .$$
If two nonzero vectors $x,y\in U$ are linearly dependent, say $y = \mu x$, we have
$$ \lambda(y)\mu x = \lambda(y)y =  f(y) = \mu f(x) = \mu \lambda(x) x $$
hence $\lambda(x) = \lambda(y).$ Therefore, $\lambda$ is constant.

Note that this also holds in finite-dimensional spaces, and in spaces over any other field of scalars than $\Bbb R.$